# SO Prisma GraphQL error: Whoops. Looks like an internal server error

Tags: mysql, docker, graphql, prisma-graphql

Making a query to bring related tables doesn't work and displays an internal server error.

I tried to change the `datamodel.prisma` schema several times without success.

When I execute this query:

```
{
  videos {
    id
    title
    sources {
      id
      quality
    }
  }
}
```

It returns this error:

```
{
  "data": {
    "videos": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "La peatonal del Vino",
        "sources": null
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Bodega Diamandes Exterior",
        "sources": null
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "title": "Con Boca",
        "sources": null
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "title": "Rep y el vino",
        "sources": null
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "title": "Pastel de chivo y ciruelas al bonarda acompañado con zapallos en manteca",
        "sources": null
      },
      {
        "id": "6",
        "title": "Séptimo Clericó",
        "sources": null
      },
      {
        "id": "7",
        "title": "Las ovejas de Kaiken",
        "sources": null
      },
      {
        "id": "8",
        "title": "Bodega Diamandes Exterior",
        "sources": null
      },
      {
        "id": "9",
        "title": "Capítulo Piloto",
        "sources": null
      }
    ]
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Whoops. Looks like an internal server error. Search your server logs for request ID: local:ck1s1nl7d001y0723idytrl5r",
      "path": [
        "videos",
        0,
        "sources"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "requestId": "local:ck1s1nl7d001y0723idytrl5r"
    },
    {
      "message": "Whoops. Looks like an internal server error. Search your server logs for request ID: local:ck1s1nl7d001y0723idytrl5r",
      "path": [
        "videos",
        1,
        "sources"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "requestId": "local:ck1s1nl7d001y0723idytrl5r"
    },
    {
      "message": "Whoops. Looks like an internal server error. Search your server logs for request ID: local:ck1s1nl7d001y0723idytrl5r",
      "path": [
        "videos",
        2,
        "sources"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "requestId": "local:ck1s1nl7d001y0723idytrl5r"
    },
    {
      "message": "Whoops. Looks like an internal server error. Search your server logs for request ID: local:ck1s1nl7d001y0723idytrl5r",
      "path": [
        "videos",
        3,
        "sources"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "requestId": "local:ck1s1nl7d001y0723idytrl5r"
    },
    {
      "message": "Whoops. Looks like an internal server error. Search your server logs for request ID: local:ck1s1nl7d001y0723idytrl5r",
      "path": [
        "videos",
        4,
        "sources"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "requestId": "local:ck1s1nl7d001y0723idytrl5r"
    },
    {
      "message": "Whoops. Looks like an internal server error. Search your server logs for request ID: local:ck1s1nl7d001y0723idytrl5r",
      "path": [
        "videos",
        5,
        "sources"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "requestId": "local:ck1s1nl7d001y0723idytrl5r"
    },
    {
      "message": "Whoops. Looks like an internal server error. Search your server logs for request ID: local:ck1s1nl7d001y0723idytrl5r",
      "path": [
        "videos",
        6,
        "sources"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "requestId": "local:ck1s1nl7d001y0723idytrl5r"
    },
    {
      "message": "Whoops. Looks like an internal server error. Search your server logs for request ID: local:ck1s1nl7d001y0723idytrl5r",
      "path": [
        "videos",
        7,
        "sources"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "requestId": "local:ck1s1nl7d001y0723idytrl5r"
    },
    {
      "message": "Whoops. Looks like an internal server error. Search your server logs for request ID: local:ck1s1nl7d001y0723idytrl5r",
      "path": [
        "videos",
        8,
        "sources"
      ],
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "requestId": "local:ck1s1nl7d001y0723idytrl5r"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my `datamodel.prisma` file:

```
"""This is a custom built-in Scalar type from LightHouse. It handles Carbon dates"""
scalar DateTime @scalar(class: "Nuwave\\Lighthouse\\Schema\\Types\\Scalars\\DateTime")

type Channel {
    id: ID! @id
    title: String! @isUnique
    description: String!
    legend: String
    shownOnPremieres: Boolean!
    shownOnTheMostSeen: Boolean!
    shownOnExploreEverything: Boolean!
    videos: [Video!]!
    banner: Banner @relation(link: INLINE)
}

type Subtitle {
    id: ID! @id
    code: String!
    description: String!
    url: String!
    video: Video! @relation(link: INLINE)
}

type Source {
    id: ID! @id
    quality: String!
    url: String!
    video: Video! @relation(link: INLINE)
}

type Video {
    id: ID! @id
    title: String! @isUnique
    sources: [Source!]!
    thumb: String!
    duration: Int!
    description: String!
    legend: String!
    shownOnPremieres: Boolean!
    shownOnTheMostSeen: Boolean!
    shownOnExploreEverything: Boolean!
    channel: Channel! @relation(link: INLINE)
    subtitles: [Subtitle!]!
}

type Banner {
    id: ID! @id
    img: String! @isUnique
    duration: String!
    backgroundColor: String!
    buttonColor: String!
    textColor: String!
    channel: Channel!
}

type User {
    id: ID! @id
    name: String!
    email: String! @isUnique
    email_verified_at: DateTime
    password: String!
    remember_token: String!
    created_at: DateTime @created_at
    updated_at: DateTime @updated_at
}
```

This is the output of the Prisma container's log:

```sh
mmagni@mmagni-lenovo:/var/www/masvino/Server$ sudo docker-compose logs | grep ck1rxkct500rq072706my60la
[sudo] password for mmagni: 
prisma_1  | {"key":"error/unhandled","requestId":"local:ck1rxkct500rq072706my60la","clientId":"default@default","payload":{"exception":"java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=397) Unknown column 'RelationTable.channel' in 'field list'","query":"{\n  channels {\n    id\n    title\n    videos {\n      id\n      title\n    }\n  }\n}\n","variables":"{}","code":"0","stack_trace":"org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:163)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:106)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:235)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:224)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.execute(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:159)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeQuery(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:173)\\n com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)\\n com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)\\n com.prisma.connector.shared.jdbc.SharedSlickExtensions.$anonfun$queryToDBIO$1(SharedSlickExtensions.scala:17)\\n com.prisma.connector.shared.jdbc.SharedSlickExtensions.$anonfun$jooqToDBIO$1(SharedSlickExtensions.scala:56)\\n slick.jdbc.SimpleJdbcAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:70)\\n slick.jdbc.SimpleJdbcAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:69)\\n slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.liftedTree1$1(BasicBackend.scala:276)\\n slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.run(BasicBackend.scala:276)\\n java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\\n java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\\n java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)","message":"(conn=397) Unknown column 'RelationTable.channel' in 'field list'"}}
prisma_1  | {"key":"error/unhandled","requestId":"local:ck1rxkct500rq072706my60la","clientId":"default@default","payload":{"exception":"java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=397) Unknown column 'RelationTable.channel' in 'field list'","query":"{\n  channels {\n    id\n    title\n    videos {\n      id\n      title\n    }\n  }\n}\n","variables":"{}","code":"0","stack_trace":"org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:163)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:106)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:235)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:224)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.execute(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:159)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeQuery(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:173)\\n com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)\\n com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)\\n com.prisma.connector.shared.jdbc.SharedSlickExtensions.$anonfun$queryToDBIO$1(SharedSlickExtensions.scala:17)\\n com.prisma.connector.shared.jdbc.SharedSlickExtensions.$anonfun$jooqToDBIO$1(SharedSlickExtensions.scala:56)\\n slick.jdbc.SimpleJdbcAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:70)\\n slick.jdbc.SimpleJdbcAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:69)\\n slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.liftedTree1$1(BasicBackend.scala:276)\\n slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.run(BasicBackend.scala:276)\\n java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\\n java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\\n java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)","message":"(conn=397) Unknown column 'RelationTable.channel' in 'field list'"}}
prisma_1  | {"key":"error/unhandled","requestId":"local:ck1rxkct500rq072706my60la","clientId":"default@default","payload":{"exception":"java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=397) Unknown column 'RelationTable.channel' in 'field list'","query":"{\n  channels {\n    id\n    title\n    videos {\n      id\n      title\n    }\n  }\n}\n","variables":"{}","code":"0","stack_trace":"org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:163)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:106)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:235)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:224)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.execute(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:159)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeQuery(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:173)\\n com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)\\n com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)\\n com.prisma.connector.shared.jdbc.SharedSlickExtensions.$anonfun$queryToDBIO$1(SharedSlickExtensions.scala:17)\\n com.prisma.connector.shared.jdbc.SharedSlickExtensions.$anonfun$jooqToDBIO$1(SharedSlickExtensions.scala:56)\\n slick.jdbc.SimpleJdbcAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:70)\\n slick.jdbc.SimpleJdbcAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:69)\\n slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.liftedTree1$1(BasicBackend.scala:276)\\n slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.run(BasicBackend.scala:276)\\n java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\\n java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\\n java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)","message":"(conn=397) Unknown column 'RelationTable.channel' in 'field list'"}}
prisma_1  | {"key":"error/unhandled","requestId":"local:ck1rxkct500rq072706my60la","clientId":"default@default","payload":{"exception":"java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=397) Unknown column 'RelationTable.channel' in 'field list'","query":"{\n  channels {\n    id\n    title\n    videos {\n      id\n      title\n    }\n  }\n}\n","variables":"{}","code":"0","stack_trace":"org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:163)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:106)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:235)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:224)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.execute(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:159)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeQuery(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:173)\\n com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)\\n com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)\\n com.prisma.connector.shared.jdbc.SharedSlickExtensions.$anonfun$queryToDBIO$1(SharedSlickExtensions.scala:17)\\n com.prisma.connector.shared.jdbc.SharedSlickExtensions.$anonfun$jooqToDBIO$1(SharedSlickExtensions.scala:56)\\n slick.jdbc.SimpleJdbcAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:70)\\n slick.jdbc.SimpleJdbcAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:69)\\n slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.liftedTree1$1(BasicBackend.scala:276)\\n slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.run(BasicBackend.scala:276)\\n java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\\n java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\\n java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)","message":"(conn=397) Unknown column 'RelationTable.channel' in 'field list'"}}
prisma_1  | {"key":"error/unhandled","requestId":"local:ck1rxkct500rq072706my60la","clientId":"default@default","payload":{"exception":"java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=397) Unknown column 'RelationTable.channel' in 'field list'","query":"{\n  channels {\n    id\n    title\n    videos {\n      id\n      title\n    }\n  }\n}\n","variables":"{}","code":"0","stack_trace":"org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:163)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:106)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:235)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:224)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.execute(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:159)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeQuery(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:173)\\n com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)\\n com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)\\n com.prisma.connector.shared.jdbc.SharedSlickExtensions.$anonfun$queryToDBIO$1(SharedSlickExtensions.scala:17)\\n com.prisma.connector.shared.jdbc.SharedSlickExtensions.$anonfun$jooqToDBIO$1(SharedSlickExtensions.scala:56)\\n slick.jdbc.SimpleJdbcAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:70)\\n slick.jdbc.SimpleJdbcAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:69)\\n slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.liftedTree1$1(BasicBackend.scala:276)\\n slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.run(BasicBackend.scala:276)\\n java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\\n java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\\n java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)","message":"(conn=397) Unknown column 'RelationTable.channel' in 'field list'"}}
prisma_1  | {"key":"error/unhandled","requestId":"local:ck1rxkct500rq072706my60la","clientId":"default@default","payload":{"exception":"java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=397) Unknown column 'RelationTable.channel' in 'field list'","query":"{\n  channels {\n    id\n    title\n    videos {\n      id\n      title\n    }\n  }\n}\n","variables":"{}","code":"0","stack_trace":"org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:163)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:106)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:235)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:224)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.execute(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:159)\\n org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeQuery(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:173)\\n com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)\\n com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)\\n com.prisma.connector.shared.jdbc.SharedSlickExtensions.$anonfun$queryToDBIO$1(SharedSlickExtensions.scala:17)\\n com.prisma.connector.shared.jdbc.SharedSlickExtensions.$anonfun$jooqToDBIO$1(SharedSlickExtensions.scala:56)\\n slick.jdbc.SimpleJdbcAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:70)\\n slick.jdbc.SimpleJdbcAction.run(StreamingInvokerAction.scala:69)\\n slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.liftedTree1$1(BasicBackend.scala:276)\\n slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$3.run(BasicBackend.scala:276)\\n java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\\n java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\\n java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)","message":"(conn=397) Unknown column 'RelationTable.channel' in 'field list'"}}
```

What can I do to get this response?

```
{
    "data": {
      "videos": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "title": "La peatonal del Vino",
          "sources": [
            {
              "id": "1",
              "quality": "320p"
            },
            {
              "id": "2",
              "quality": "480p"
            },
            {
              "id": "3",
              "quality": "1080p"
            }
          ]
        },

        ...

      ]
    }
}
```

I have tried a lot of things without success. The `sources` field keeps coming `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to dump database content to backup file, drop all tables on the database, re-deploy the prisma application and import the backup file back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

The error says 'Unknown column `RelationTable.channel`. it should be linked with columns and relation. Maybe try to reset your environment:

Try `prisma export`. Delete you database. and recreate with `prisma deploy`. Then re upload your data with `prisma import`

**Old answer**

Try to add an explicit relation name between `Source` and `Video` in your dataModel.

```
type Source {
    id: ID! @id
    quality: String!
    url: String!
    video: Video! @relation(name: "VideoSource")
}

type Video {
    id: ID! @id
    title: String! @isUnique
    sources: [Source!]! @relation(name: "VideoSource")
    thumb: String!
    duration: Int!
    description: String!
    legend: String!
    shownOnPremieres: Boolean!
    shownOnTheMostSeen: Boolean!
    shownOnExploreEverything: Boolean!
    channel: Channel! @relation(link: INLINE)
    subtitles: [Subtitle!]!
}
```

Comment: I tried that, same result. It didn't worked! I'm starting to think that maybe be is a Prisma's bug.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Prisma? You should try their slack channel

Comment: The error says 'Unknown column 'RelationTable.channel''. it should be linked with columns and relation. Try prisma export. Delete you database. and recreate with prisma deploy. Then re upload your data with prisma import